# Load image from API with @GET request in Glide

Tags: android, api, kotlin, rx-java2, android-glide

How i can load an image from an `API` method who uses `@GET` and return me a photo into an `ImageView` using Glide?
Im using an VMMV Architecture so i have my repository and returning chains of `Observables` using `RxJava`.

I try to use the conventional mode of `Glide` by an URL request with a header:

```
       Glide
            .with(this)
            .load(glideUrl)
            .into(img_main_profile)
```

But it doesn't work.

```
    glideUrl = GlideUrl(
        BASE_URL.plus("/api/user/profile_image?size=thumbnail"),
        LazyHeaders.Builder().addHeader("Authorization", token).build())
```

Comment: first make a http request via retrofit and then use response which contains related url in order to be able download and load image into your image view

Comment: But the request returns me a photo, not the URL.

Comment: what's the log output about this request?

Comment: I can't track the log of a Retrofit request (?)

Comment: I solve my problem with another method, thanks anyway.

Comment: share your method please

Comment: I use the same method,but instead of the VM in the Fragment